# What not have I done for you?

Tags: riddle

> You check me when you are bored,
>   You use me when you are hungry,
>   You find comfort in me when you are tired.
>
> I would have even taken you to the answer, but not anymore.

**Who/what am I?**

**Hint**

> I am recently getting over it.

Comment: **I would have even taken you to the answer, but not anymore.** Is this line is also the part of the riddle?

Comment: @Siraj, Yes it is.

Comment: Damn, now I have to remove my almost complete written answer. :(

Comment: I'm sure your solution differs from mine. ;-)

Comment: I was going to say **Myself** too. Actually there are many things that fits into that riddle.

Answer (score 8):

Are you

> A mother

Explanation:

You check me when bored

> When bored as a child you would go to your mother for fun

You use me when you are hungry

> When you want food your mother would feed you

You find comfort in me when you are tired

> When tired you sleep and find comfort with your mother

I would have even taken you to the answer, but not anymore

> A mother used to give you many answers in life but not anymore after growing up

Answer (score 4):

I will guess

> time

You check me when you are bored,

> People check the time when they are bored with something and want to get it over with.

You use me when you are hungry,

> Not too sure - maybe refers to the fact that most people eat their meals at set times? Or maybe that you use time a lot in cooking?

You find comfort in me when you are tired.

> When it is late, you find comfort that you can go to bed after a long day.

I would have even taken you to the answer, but not anymore.

> Eventually, over time, the answer will be revealed, but since I'm posting it now, you no longer need to wait!

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to guess that it is:

> A mobile phone

*You check me when you are bored*

> We fiddle with our phones when bored or when we have nothing better to do

*You use me when you are hungry*

> Presumably to order out

*You find comfort in me when you are tired*

> We use our phone for music/movies/games and similar forms of entertainment

*I would have even taken you to the answer*

> We can use our phones to search the Internet for answers to myriad questions

*but not anymore*

This one has me stumped.

> But I'm going to guess that instead of searching for the answer using my phone I'm now wracking my brains for the right answer, hence the phone per se is useless as I'm staring off into space.

Comment: Nice try. But not quite what I had in mind.

Comment: This is the same thing I thought of.

Comment: This line must came in almost everyone's mind (including me) just because of line **You check me when you are bored**.

Comment: Mobile phone can literally be a solution for any riddle here as you can do anything with a mobile phone nowadays (and if that's not enough, you can change the answer to a "future mobile phone" and then you're unlimited at all)

Answer (score 2):

> If I am bored, all I can do is to check *myself.* When I am hungry, it's *me,* who has to eat. When I am tired, *I* am going to rest. As soon as I realise, that I am the answer, there is *no you* anymore. *I am* the answer!

Answer (score 0):

I think

> Neurotransmitter

You check me when you are bored

> Might be the dopamine check at the time of boredom.

You use me when you are hungry

> Hunger and satiety is regulated by a neurotransmitter as per this [link](https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/1998/05/980506080957.htm)

You find comfort in me when you are tired.

> We find comfort in sleep/rest when we are tired. neurotransmitter plays an important role in [sleep](https://www.howsleepworks.com/how_neurological.html).

I would have even taken you to the answer, but not anymore.

> Of course neurotransmitters play important roles in decision making.
> *But not anymore* : It cannot, because we already got the answer.

The Title : What not have I done for you?

> Neurotransmitters are what tell your heart to beat, lungs to breath, and stomach to digest. Overall they play an important role in our body. [Reference](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-importance-of-neurotransmitters).

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure about it,

> **The Internet**

You check me when you are bored

> The Internet is the first priority nowadays whenever we get bored. We use Facebook, Instagram and so on.

You use me when you are hungry

> Surely we use our internet to order some food whenever we are hungry and don't wanna cook.

You find comfort in me when you are tired

> After the tiredness of the whole day, we find comfort using the internet, spend our time on the internet, and rest.

I would have even taken you to the answer, but not anymore.

> With the help of the internet, I came up here to answer, which was not possible with anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Is it:

> A car that recently broke down?

Explanation:

> You check the oil when you're bored. Drive to get food. Sleep in the back. But now it's broken?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is

> hand

You check me when you are bored

> To check the time on our watch

You use me when you are hungry

> Obvious

You find comfort in me when you are tired

> We rest our head on our hands

I would have even taken you to the answer, but not anymore.

> We could have used our hand to google the answer, but that is not possible as this is an original riddle.